# MMA8451q Linear freefall using KL25Z

Tags: c, embedded

I'm new to embedded coding and in the learning stage. how to code MMA8451q using KL25Z to make the LED glow when it detects freefall ? in MCUexpresso

Comment: New to StackOverflow too it seems.  You need to ask a more specific question.  No one will write that code for you (and without hardware details it would be difficult in any case), but we will help with specific issues you have.  For example it is not clear whether you are having difficulty knowing how to build and load code using your IDE or or if the issue is controlling an LED, reading the accelerometer, or processing the data from the accelerometer (which is perhaps a math/algorithm issue and not specifically an embedded development issue).

Comment: Moreover KL25Z defines the MCU not the hardware.  If you are using a COTS development board with the accelerometer and LED on board, it would be useful to specify the board being used.

Comment: I suggest you break down you task into 1) LED driver, 2) Accelerometer driver (need  I2C I/O), 3) Putting those two together. Looking at the data sheet it seems that the accelerometer has freefall  function built in - so no complex algorithms).